# ADO.NET and working with different db

Tags: c#, ado.net

I need to implement reading data from one db and insert/update data in two other databases (Db2 and Db3). All databases are SQL Server.

Now I'm using the next scenario:

- Open connection and start transaction for my source db.

  1.1 Open connection and start transaction for Db2

  1.2 Insert/Update records.

  1.3 Commit/Rollback transaction

  2.1 Open connection and start transaction for Db3

  2.2 Insert/Update records.

  2.3 Commit/Rollback transaction
- Mark record as exported in source db.
- Commit transaction.

Everything is working correct. But if I have exception in 1.2 or 2.2 steps, the current transaction will be rolled back, but transaction from other step will stay committed.

How I can implement scenario when if  steps (1.2 or 2.2) have exception, steps 1.3 and 2.3 
will be rolled back, too?

I can't use one transaction for Db2 and Db3 because I have exception

> The transaction is either not associated with the current connection
>   or has been completed.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

UPDATE:
I solved my problem:
Now I'm using the next scenario:

- Open connection and start transaction for my source db.

  1.1 Open connection and start transaction for Db1

  1.2 Open connection and start transaction for Db2

  1.3 Insert/Update in DB1

  1.4 Insert/Update in DB2

  1.5 Commit/Rollback transaction for Db1

  1.6 Commit/Rollback transaction for Db2
- Mark record as exported in source db.
- Commit transaction.

Comment: how do you handle when Db1 transaction succeed and Db2 transaction failure?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class to interact with multiple databases inside a single distributed transaction.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  //put all logic here
  scope.Complete();
}
```

Here's another [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/TransactionScope20.aspx)

Comment: @ukraine You can use [System.EnterpriseServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.aspx) here's an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/KdotNET.aspx). But `TransactionScope` approach is simple.